# ¿Tendría problemas si instalo git teniendo SVN?

Tags: ubuntu, git, svn

Tengo instalado rabbitvcs en UBUNTU para el control de versiones de mi pagina web, me gustaría realizar un curso de git para compararlas y a lo mejor dar el salto de una a la otra, pero no estoy del todo seguro si me daría problemas, ya que mientras realice el curso de git seguiría trabajando con SVN

Comment: como tal, git es un comando como svn u otro. el hecho de instalarlos no te dara problemas. Usarlos con la misma carpeta no deberia darte problemas (porque cada uno usa su propia carpeta de datos), pero te sugiero que te copies la carpeta de la web en otro sitio y la utilices para el curso por separado. Ya tendras tiempo de dejar svn (y venir al maravilloso mundo de git)

Comment: muchas gracias compañero, si me dejas el comentario en la parte de respuestas podre ponerlo como comentario acertado ;)

Comment: Si vas a tener conviviendo git y svn en el mismo espacio, sería recomendable que añadieses todas las carpetas .svn al .gitignore, e ignorases la carpeta .git desde tu cliente de svn.